# Rate limit for this resource has been exceeded

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-cloud

I was trying to log into BitBucket.

[image]

I kept getting this error

[image]

> Rate limit for this resource has been exceeded

Is BitBucket require us to login via a different URL ?

Any hints on this ?

Comment: Are you connecting over IPv6?

Comment: @JimRedmond: No, just normal IPv4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error when using https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/

I found I was able to get in without error by first using https://id.atlassian.com/login?application=bitbucket .

Hope that helps you as it did me.